# How can I completely remove GitHub repositories from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, github, repository

I've got a real mess with my GitHub repositories for two Xcode (Swift) apps named "y2go" and "Y2GOsp". What I would like to do is completely remove all repositories from "everywhere" (GitHub, Apps, My Mac) and just start over with a fresh create and push. However, I can't figure out how to remove them.

I have used `rm -rf .git` from the app folder, but they're still there. Plus, it has somehow merged the two apps together.

[image]

Is there some way I can completely remove the repositories so they don't show up in Xcode for the apps at all. I know how to delete them from GitHub, and could then use Xcode to re-create the repositories and then do a push.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problems with git changes and git repositories in Xcode. I solved the problem with this:

1 - I deleted from xcode project all files added from another projects by menu: File > Add file to your project
I believe the Xcode automatically add related projects in git changes and repositories when you do this.

2 - I disabled the git source control in menu: Xcode > Settings > Source Control tab > enable source control button

3 - I closed the Xcode and clean the cash using the DevCleaner software avaiable on App Store.

4 - Enable source control again and the projects its gonna be removed and just the main repository you are working it was avaiable.

Xcode version: 15.0
Mac version: 14.1.2